# Understanding query with REGEX expressions

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

So I'm looking at the documentation of something left behind by a former employee who has been gone for awhile. I understand Regex, I just don't know what's going on in this scenario.

```
TABLE_QUERY(server_logs_abc, 'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"^def_[A-Za-z0-9]{5}_[\d]{8}") and datediff( current_timestamp(), timestamp( regexp_extract(table_id,r"(\d{8})$") ) ) < 30')
```

There are also daily tables that look like this

```
iserver_cogs_abc.def_4J389_20180221
iserver_cogs_abc.def_4J389_20180220
iserver_cogs_abc.def_4J389_20180219
iserver_cogs_abc.def_4J389_20180218
```

And so on chronologically.

So I understand the two regex expressions. The first for `REGEXP_MATCH` is the naming convention:

```
def_4J389_2018XXXX
```

(XXXX representing the month and day timecode i.e 0221)

And the second Regex in `REGEXP_EXTRACT` is the 8-digit time code (i.e `20180221`)

But what does it all mean when put together. Also, what does that leading `r`mean that proceeds the two Regex portions (i.e `r"^def_[A-Za-z0-9]{5}_[\d]{8}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second regex extracts YYYYMMDD portion of table name which then is translated into timestamp and finally gets compared with current timestamp and DATEDIFF then returns number of the days between those two timestamps

So together they return return only last 30 days tables that match pattern from first regex

As of `r` - when used as prefix to string - it makes it so called raw string that is used widely in regular expression. for example - You can escape "\", "_", or "%" using two backslashes. For example, "\%". If you are using raw strings, only a single backslash is required. For example, r"\%"
I recommend you to google for raw / literal string to get more details on this